Change picture size in winforms
i have an img in this button, how can i chang the size of the image?
            // btnProfile
            // 
            this.btnProfile.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnProfile.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnProfile.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnProfile.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(147)))), ((int)(((byte)(149)))), ((int)(((byte)(169)))));
            this.btnProfile.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btnProfile.Image")));
            this.btnProfile.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.btnProfile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 310);
            this.btnProfile.Name = "btnProfile";
            this.btnProfile.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            this.btnProfile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(233, 41);
            this.btnProfile.TabIndex = 9;
            this.btnProfile.Text = "Profile";
            this.btnProfile.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
            this.btnProfile.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

i used
Image originalImage = (Image)resources.GetObject("btnProfile.Image");
Image resizedImage = new Bitmap(originalImage, new Size(20, 20));

but it did not work :<

You should not try to resize a Bitmap (its not a vector format) this will get you mostly just ugly crap. Put the image in the correct size into the resources (that have been created with a fitting tool or explicitly created for that size) . And if you need the same image in different sizes put it multiple times into the resource. Then choose the fitting image in the resource according to the needed size.

I don't see where you assign btnProfile.Image = resizedImage.

at least ,I uploaded the photo online and resized it :D, tks all

@Ralf, downsizing bitmaps used on buttons shouldn't be a problem, the quality can be specifically improved. Saving or using for further processing even downsized images is likely bad idea, I agree. To me it's obvious OP is trying to reduce the size, but I might be wrong.
